# is it safe to change the database page verify option from torn_page_detection to checksum?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2005, optimization

We have been alerted to a page verify configuration error for the following databases (eIQSystem, eIQLegislation, eIQMeta and 000Company) on server SERVER01.

This monitor checks the Page Verify setting for the database mentioned above.

The Page Verify Setting discovers damaged database pages caused by disk I/O path errors.

Disk I/O path errors can be the cause of database corruption problems and are generally caused by power failures or disk hardware failures that occur at the time the page is being written to disk.

The databases option has been set to TORN_PAGE_DETECTION. Microsoft recommends that the setting must change to checksum as part of best practice. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb402873.aspx.

there is this discussion between [checksum x page torn detection](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic663009-266-1.aspx) but there is no objective conclusion.

there is a good article regarding 
[performance comparison between checksum and page torn](http://dba-presents.com/index.php/sql-server/22-checksum-vs-torn-page-detection-performance)

Can we change the setting to checksum? is it safe? (would it affect any application)?

Comment: Checksum is far better as compared to torn_page_detection option. There is no doubt about this.

Comment: After changing the option to CHECKSUM, make sure you take a full backup with verify CHECKSUM and a restore to another server with verify CHECKSUM.

Comment: @ScottHodgin if you can elaborate a bit more on this, any special reason for doing that? I am not challenging, I just want to be on the safe side, but I have some big databases around here, if I could get away without doing what you suggested I would be glad.

Comment: Actually, the existing data needs to be read into memory, changed and written back out for the PAGE CHECKSUM to be usable.  Read this post from @PaulRandal

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-1730-page-checksums/